# how to create rounded edges on box using Autodesk Inventor? using overlayed plastic

Tags: mechanical-engineering, autodesk-inventor

[image]the wood texture is an overlay, underneath is plastic

If sanded it takes the face of the plastic off. Im looking to round the sharp corners.

the idea i'm working from now is using the same sharp corners , putting a 90 degree angle aluminum moulding piece , either using super glue to hold it to the box (not preferable) or using rivets to hold it in place. The panels are 7 mm thick.

i appreciate any feedback, suggestions on this . 
looking to keep the box together and then round the corners so that it's no longer sharp.

Comment: The title of your post suggests that this is a CAD problem. The post suggests that you have completed the build and you are now trying to modify the physical object. You have tagged it as "structural engineering" which means that it is about building structures. This is a mess. I think you should [edit] the question, remove the irrelevant information and tags and add a photo. Also explain why you want to round the corners and then put something over them.

Comment: i appreciate the feedback and suggestion. It was understood and adjusted @Transistor

Comment: The title still mentions "inventor CAD" which I presume is meant to be "Inventor CAD" (Autodesk Inventor). (Capitals matter.) But it's not clear what CAD has to do with the question as applying a fillet or chamfer to the corners is a trivial task in most solid modelling CAD programs.

Comment: You might be looking for [cabinet+ball+corner+fittings](https://www.google.com/search?q=cabinet+ball+corner+fittings).

Comment: WOAH! those are awesome @Transistor , that's like exactly right. Wow, you may not know but that is EXACTLY and incredibly suitable for my project. I appreciate it. That's a good answer.
a large part about this project is that it's utilizing a material that cannot have the face removed,  that removes fillet or chamfer from processing

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer so you can mark the question answered. I still have no idea what this has to do with any kind of CAD.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [ball+corner](https://www.google.com/search?q=ball+corner). (Use the image search.)

[image]

*Figure 1. Ball corners are commonly used on flight cases for musical instruments, band equipment and scientific or engineering equipment.*